# What could be causing low water pressure in cold line in only one bathroom sink?

Tags: plumbing

My back bathroom sink just started having low water pressure on the cold side only,,, all tubs and other sinks are fine,,, my house is less than 20 years old and plumbed with pex only,,, I have taken the valve off the faucet and looked for clogs and were none and shut the water off and checked the ball valve for that side at the sink,,, no clogs,,, it even runs low into a bucket,,, I know it must be a clog but how on pex only and just one water line to one sink only? Can't see a kink happening on a system that has had no work and has been fine for years.

Comment: How is the house plumbed? Is there a manifold with valves on each line to each use point?

Comment: Remove the water line from the faucet and run it into a bucket and calculate the GPM this way and compare it to another faucet. Also, does this branch off to the tub? As in, from water supply, to faucet, to tub on the same line? If so, and the tub is good, you can narrow your search to the valve under the sink, the hose to the faucet, or the faucet cartridge. The valve could be bad. Only way to test that is to make sure it is open completely and if water is slow or low pressure, then replace the valve. This is the valve on the wall.